# EF 6 code first update table in the InitializeDatabase

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first

i`m working with EF 6 and code first. I already have an operative database, which i added one more table (table2), relationed 1xN to other table (table1).
In the initializeDatabase(context), I added one record into the new table (table2). The question is: How can I update all records of the table1 with the FK, with the id of the recently inserted record into table2. If i do nothing, the fk field update to NULL, but i want to update with the id of the inserted record.

Here I insert into the new table:

```
public override void InitializeDatabase(AppContext context)
{
   var storeTypes = context.StoreTypes.FirstOrDefault();
   if (storeTypes != null) return;
   context.StoreTypes.Add(new StoreType { Name = "Local", Description = "Local" });
   context.StoreTypes.Add(new StoreType { Name = "Gondola", Description = "Gondola" });
   context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I can't really tell from your question what tables you are dealing with, so I will assume StoreTypes is the lookup table and Stores in the main table? I'm not used to seeing Seed() code in InitializeDatabase, but I suppose that would work.

```
public override void InitializeDatabase(AppContext context)
{

   if (!context.StoreTypes.Any(st => st.Name == "Local"))
   {
       var newStoreType = new StoreType { Name = "Local", Description = "Local" };
       context.SaveChanges();  // newStoreType will now have id
       var storesToUpdate = context.Stores.Where(s => s.StoreTypeId == 0);
       storesToUpdate.ForEach(s => s.StoreTypeId = newStoreType.Id);
       context.SaveChanges();
   }
}
```